# How can I install a systemd service using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, systemd

I want to install a systemd service from a Jinja2 template. How do I do this?

Do I have to use `copy` module to copy the file to `/lib/systemd/system` and then use `systemd` module to enable it?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 68):

I use the `template` module to install the `.service` file into the `/etc/systemd/system`. According to [this digital ocean blog post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) `/lib/systemd/system` should be reserved for packages bundled with the OS itself, and third party services should be defined in `/etc/systemd/system`.

With ansible's `systemd` module I'd start the service with `daemon_reload=yes`.

**Prior to Ansible 2.2**: I do a `systemctl daemon-reload` afterward (can use an ansible handler for this if appropriate) to prod systemd to pick up the new file.

```
- name: install myservice systemd unit file
  template: src=myservice.j2 dest=/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service

- name: start myservice
  systemd: state=started name=myservice daemon_reload=yes


# For ansilble < 2.2 only
#- name: reload systemd unit configuration
#  command: systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: The post doesn't mandate that user modules should be in `/etc/systemd/system`, just suggested that it takes precedence. Normally when you do `systemctl enable`, it creates a symlink from `/lib/systemd/system` to `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA It is not good practice to install user files on `/lib`. It should be left for system packages.

Comment: This will reload the systemd daemon EVERY TIME the playbook is executed, which makes this solution non-idempotent. Ideally, you only want to reload the daemon IF the first task resulted in a change, so a handler would be a better option for idempotency.

Comment: ... and don't forget to use handlers/notify